# Django Admin Dashboard and Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django framework and Django Rest Framework. In views.py file, I have added two class based REST APIs, one is  derived from generic.ListCreateAPIView and the another one is derived from generic.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.  Similarly in Django Framework based web application, in views.py file I have added class based views derived from generic.ListView and generic.DetailView. My question is when executing localhost:8000/admin the app is displayed in the browser , I am able to do CRUD operations, would the admin dashboard actions call functions or API in Views.py file or not? In admin.py file we are registering only model objects.

Comment: The admin site has it's own views that it uses when Creating/Destroying/etc, it's packaged in by default, so it doesn't use any of the view.py that you've created.
I believe you can find them in `contrib\admin\options.py`